# Появление блока по нажатию

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Перейдя по ссылке - https://bpd4.backpackerdeals.com/deal можно увидеть Booking calendar, в котором по нажатию на день под ним появляется блок с position: relative. Как это можно осуществить? Именно что бы блок появлялся под днем на который кликнули. Календарь построен на Grid. Так же прикрепил скрин. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LD1tV.png

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы понять как это реализовать вам нужно изучить в `JavaScript` событие `onclick` - https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events (лучше прочитать всё полностью и выполнить задания).
А также как изменять документ - https://learn.javascript.ru/modifying-document, также это всё лучше прочитать и выполнить все задания.
После этого вы сможете добавить нужный блок в разметку `HTML` с помощью `JavaScript`, при клике по нужному элементу.
Вставил пример, как может выглядеть подобный код

```js
var button = document.querySelector(".button");
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = "copy";
    div.innerHTML = "<strong>Всем привет!</strong> Вы прочитали важное сообщение.";
    document.body.append(div);
});
```

```css
.button {
    color: black;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 15px 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid black;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.copy {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 5px auto 0;
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: 5px 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">Нажми для блока</div>
```

Comment: Вопрос вообще не о том, автор хочет создавать блок под нажатым элементом, а как его создавать я думаю он знает